# .htaccess ampersand to question mark and remove index.php

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want change url from 
http://example.com/index.php?city=newyork&cat=apple&q=ipad
TO
http://example.com/newyork?cat=apple&q=ipad

Please help me.

I have  .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)(?:$|\?(?:.+)) /index.php?city=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA,NE]
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: tell me please how if include character '-' ?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city=([^&]*)&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1?%2
```

References: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString